# Unable to access phpMyAdmin on a LAMP setup on an Azure server

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, azure

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin on LAMP on Azure. Everything is working properly, I just checked my server `.net/info.php`.

I succesfully installed phpMyAdmin using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

But when I go to:

```
.net/phpmyadmin/
```

I get the following 404 error on browser tab. What can i do?

> "Not Found
>   The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ".net" Port 80"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), Apache loads configuration files from the `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory which is managed with the `a2enconf` command.

Therefore if you need to manually include the phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache configuration file you must run the following:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf   
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin  
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```